# status bar color in iOS 13 with modal ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have black status bar in my app. Also I have `present modally` mode in one of my controllers. But when I use `present modally` my controller have card design and top part of my background under stats bar turns black but my status bar not change color on white automatically. How to fix it?

image in my case:
[image: image in my case]

image like I want to do:
[image: image like I want to do]

Comment: What you describe, where the status bar turns white when the black appears behind it during a sheet presentation, is the normal behavior. If that isn't happening, _you_ must be doing something wrong. You have done something to the status bar. But you have not told us what it is.

Comment: Provide screenshots and the code snippet that you are facing the issue.

Comment: @Nandish add new screenshots

Comment: @matt in info, plist I have `status bar Dark Style` only

Comment: Well that's the problem. Delete that. I've given it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your Info.plist.

- If you have a Status bar style setting in the Info.plist, delete it.
- If you have a View controller based status bar setting in the Info.plist, delete it.

Manage your status bar properly, through the top-level view controller, and all will be well.

Comment: Ok. And what code I should add in `ViewController`? Pleas show in answer. Because I googled some ways but it doesn't work ...

Comment: That answer depends on where you are in the view controller hierarchy. You have not given that information. But I assure you that if you delete those entries from the Info.plist you will have exactly what you asked for: a dark text, except during the modal presentation when you will have a light text. Try it.

Comment: I do this in my project but my status bar is light. But I create new project and in this project all work fine. I don't understand where issue in my old project...

Comment: Also I use background image with orange color. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: You have not answered my question about what your view controller hierarchy is, so I can't help any further. I told you why the status bar was not changing color and that is what you asked.

Comment: I have NavigationController -> TabBarController -> TableViewController -> Next TableViewController  ->  ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Status bar style` and set it to `Light Content` as below and try

[image]

Comment: already have. Nothing changes

Comment: Try another option in Info.plist updated in my answer.

Comment: It is helped. But now in all my app I have white status bar. But I need to black

Comment: This is wrong. The correct approach is to have _neither_ of those in the Info.plist.

Comment: Why do you think it is a incorrect approach ?

Comment: @Nandish Any ideas how to change status bar text color on black?